# Hadoop Reducer - get input directory in new API?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

In my input directory, I have a list of files to process as well as a metadata file.  On the output reducer side, I'd like to index into this file and just add the extra metadata to the output.  How can I get the input directory?

In the old API, one could do this:

```
context.getConfiguration().get("map.input.dir")
```

The new API allows the mapper to do this:

```
(FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath()
```

But the Reducer context does not have this function.  Also, doing a join seems overkill for the simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reducer` runs on the outputs of the `Mappers`, so no information about the input files is available in the `Context` there. Now to identify the input directory inside `reduce` you just need to tag the outValue in `map` using the code you shared, joining is irrelevant here. Eg :

**MAP**

```
String tag = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath()
                                                .getParent().getName().toString();
context.write(outKey, new Text(tag + "_" + value.toString));
```

If you're interested in the fileName itself (which should be the case indeed), remove the  `getParent()` call.

**REDUCE**

```
String metaFileName = "meta.dat";
for(Text value : values){
    String[] tagVal = value.toString().split("_",2); 
    if(strVal[0].equals(metaFileName){
          // process the meta file here // strVal[1] contains the actual value
    } else { // process data files }
}
```

This should solve your problem. One suggestion here, you may take advantage of the `MultiOutputs` api to write to different types of file from reducer. Otherwise after the job is over, it will be really  hard to identify the metaFile(which will be distributed among several output files).

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but doesn't this require making my MapOutputValuClass? I'm doing other processing with the mappers, which output Map of <IntWritable, IntWritable>. Sure, I could make a nested map to differentiate metadata and parse on the reducer side, but that seems inefficient

Comment: Although looks inefficient, it's a common practice. I see no other way if some processing has to be done for the meta in the `Reducer`. On the other hand, u may process it separately in a different `Mapper` using `MultipleInputs` which still needs the same `if-else` block in the reduce. How large is ur metafile by the way ?

Comment: Ah ok, I was just confused as the old API seemed to allow this.  The only thing the reducer is joining the metadata: e.g. looking up metadata (via a key) adding it to the existing output, though it could certainly do some simple processing based on it.  The metafile is currently pretty small.

Comment: Then simply use `DistributedCache` and load meta in a `Map` object(or any suitable data structure) inside `setup` of the `Mapper`. You won't need a `Reducer` anymore !

Answer (score 0):

Input to a MapReduce job is specified by the `FileInputFormat.addInputPath()` method.  As the method name implies, the `addInputPath()` method may be called more than once to specify additional files and/or directories as input to the MapReduce job.  There may therefore potentially be multiple paths as input to a single MapReduce job.

A Mapper task operates on a single split.  Thus it makes sense for a Mapper to be able to retrieve the path for the particular split that is is processing.

Reducers however typically operate on the output of multiple mappers whose input splits may (possibly) have had different paths.  Therefore within a Reducer there isn't a concept of an InputSplit, which is why you can't get a path to it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, so how can I do my simple task of getting  metadata into my map task output? Do I have to write a separate one job mapper to add it?

Comment: blackSmith's solution is a sound and solid approach.  Read the metadata in the mapper, and then concatenate the metadata to the mapper "value" output using a delimiter that should not occur naturally within your data.  Within your reducer you will then separate the two values and process them.